# Laravel multiple roles on same route

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel-routing, laravel-5.1

This are currently my route implementation for `user` and `auth` roles on Laravel 5.1:

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'admin', 'middleware' => 'auth:administrator'], function()
{
    $a = 'admin.';
    Route::get('/', ['as' => $a . 'home', 'uses' => 'AdminController@getHome']);
});

Route::group(['prefix' => 'user', 'middleware' => 'auth:user'], function()
{
    $a = 'user.';
    Route::get('/', ['as' => $a . 'home', 'uses' => 'UserController@getHome']);
});
```

I have another role where `user` can signup as `merchant`, but the issue is, how can I implement `merchant` route without duplicating the code, since both `user` and `merchant` using similar dashboard where `merchant` have extra features.

The implementation that currently worked is:

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'user', 'middleware' => 'auth:merchant'], function()
    {
        $a = 'user.';
        Route::get('/', ['as' => $a . 'home', 'uses' => 'UserController@getHome']);
    });
```

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to pass on a list of middlewares to your route using an array.

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'user', 'middleware' => ['auth:user', 'auth:merchant']], function()
{
    $a = 'user.';
    Route::get('/', ['as' => $a . 'home', 'uses' => 'UserController@getHome']);
});
```

However, I am not sure if this yields a result which does what you hope to achieve. Perhaps all this does is only allowing the route to users which belong to roles "user" AND "merchant", which probably isn't what you intend to do.